# How to copy the data into one excel file at the time of mapping running in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I want to copy the data into one excel file, while the mapping has been running in informatica.

Answer (score 0):

I used Informatica last year, now am on SSIS. If I remember correctly, you can setup a separate connection for Excel target destination. There after you pretty much drag all fields from your source to the target destination (in this case Excel).

Answer (score 0):

As usual develop a mapping with source and target.
But make target as Flat File while creating target.
Then run the mapping u will get